# loop through a csv with a column of URLs and post a http request for each url

Tags: python, csv, http, request

trying to loop through a csv with a column of URLs and  post a http request for each url, parse the response html for a url and store the url into a new column. I've been looking through similar posts on here trying to script kiddie my way into finishing this task but i'm at a loss. any assistance is appreciated greatly.

so all I have so far is importing csv and requests and opening a csv file.

```
import requests
import csv 

with open('UsersWithoutSignaturesOU.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    errors = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            r = requests.get(row['thumbnailPhotoUrl'])
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `requests.post()` rather than `requests.get()`? `post()` is for posting form data.

Comment: Use Beautiful Soup to parse the response.

Comment: @Barmar i'm a complete noob, so I assume you're correct and will use `requests.post()`instead

Comment: How would I go about using beautiful soup ?

Comment: That's more than can be answered here. Read a tutorial on web scraping.

Comment: Are the URLs all from the same website?  i.e. same format?  Otherwise you are going to find it difficult to extract things consistently. You would need to add an example URL and show your expected output in your question (use the [edit] button)